# When the indexer class functions are triggered in magento2

Tags: indexer, magento2.2

I have created custom indexer for my custom module and a row is showing in manage indexer page in backend after cleared cache.
I have created a indexer class and implements \Magento\Framework\Indexer\ActionInterface, \Magento\Framework\Mview\ActionInterface class as these two class are interface so we must implements all functions those are decalared in two interface. 
I want to know that these four execute,executeFull,executeList(array $ids),executeRow($id) function When triggered.please check below class for reference.

```
    namespace Ezest\Practice\Model\Indexer;
    class Test implements \Magento\Framework\Indexer\ActionInterface, 
    \Magento\Framework\Mview\ActionInterface
    {   
    public function execute($ids){
        //code here!
    }
    public function executeFull(){
            //code here!
    }
    public function executeList(array $ids){
    //code here!
    }
    public function executeRow($id){
            //code here!
    }
    }
```

Comment: Below class? Did you forget adding it?

Comment: class has been added.

Answer (score 0):

**executeFull**: execute will call when you run indexing from the command line. It will do full reindex for all the id's for that entity.

**executeRow**: executeRow will indexing individual row. It usually invokes when you save individual entity id like catalog_product,salesrule_rule etc.

When you have set your indexing as "Update by Schedule". In that case, it will generate the virtual table with postfix "_cl". This table contains 2 columns as below:
version_id
entity_id

At this time executeList will comes into the picture.

**executeList**: executeList will find the difference between last version id and current version id. Between that, it indexing all the entity_ids.

**execute**: execute will invoke based on the data that are stored in the mview_state table. It will reindex entities which are there in the mview_state table. This will again work when you have set indexing to "Update by Schedule".

Comment: Hi Darshan,
Thanku for giving the answer 
I understood the explanation about executeFull and i tried it with practical and found positve result. 
And I understood the explanation about "Update by Schedule" and i tried it and got clear picture. 
suppose i have a custom eav module  i want to create custom indexer for this like mangento doing for vendor module. 
If i write code inside executeRow,executeList,execute will it execute automaticly  or will i have to execute it by calling it as you said executeRow would call while change entity. 
I want to get clear picture on other functions.

Comment: Do you have any refference on this?.